# Debugging Javascript/ReactJS errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a small application with `ReactJS` and sometimes find it difficult to debug it.

Every time I make some `Javascript error`, like missing `let/var` in front of new variable, missing `require` for a component that I later use, my application just stops working (the code does not execute beyond the line where the error is), but I'm not getting any errors in browser's console. It seems as if some ReactJS code was intercepting errors, maybe handling them some custom way. Is there anything like that in ReactJS? How can I see errors in the console?

I'm using `gulp/gulp-connect/browserify` set to run the application.

Let me know if you need any additional data or code samples, I'll update the question.

Comment: I need your help again. You try to see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672098/pass-array-from-controller-to-view-laravel-5. I commented on your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you know that an error is thrown but swallowed by some other code, you can enable in your browser's debugger to pause execution when an exception is thrown, even if it is caught somewhere:

[image]

Note however that libraries sometimes deliberately trigger exceptions while testing whether the browser supports certain features. You'd have to step over those.

Comment: It helps, but makes testing the application rather complicated - after every page reload I need to click through some exceptions that libraries throw. If ReactJS swallows exceptions, i'm sure there is a way to display them, via some custom error handler or sth. Hiding errors and not giving access to them makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Usage of [React Hot Loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) which is a Webpack plugin should solve most of the problems you have in a development process. It's easy to [integrate](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/) into existing project and has [quite a few examples](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/master/docs#starter-kits) how to put all the things together.

As a result:

- your code changes would be pushed to the browser
- in case of the error you will have meaningful stack trace in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the incorrect JS syntax is causing your gulp process to fail which would result in your application not being bundled/deployed in the browser at all.

It seems like there should be errors in your system console (where gulp is running) - as opposed to your browser console. Possibly your gulp process crashes when this happens too. If there are no errors in your console, you may have to listen for them. [This post](https://truongtx.me/2014/07/15/handle-errors-while-using-gulp-watch/) has an example of how to log errors from browserify:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function(){
  var b = browserify();
  b.add('./main.js');

  return b.bundle()
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log(err.message); //
      this.end();
    })
    .pipe(source('main.out.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Probably the best solution is to run your code through jshint before browserify so that you aren't trying to browserify syntactically invalid code.

Caveat: not a current gulp user

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the similar problem with this like missing let/var, require, and other trivial mistakes inside of the react context.
In my case, the cause is the mistake of Promise statement. Promise seems to suppress any exceptions that occur after it is called. 
I could resolve the problem by handling exception like below.

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;
var promise = new Promise(...)
promise
  .then(function(data){...})
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e.stack)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) is a starter kit and it shows error at compile time and shows stack trace on the browser. It also has testing set up.