# How to pass array from controller to view (Laravel 5)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My array ($response_array) is like this :

```
Array
(
    [Auth] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => test
            [UserIP] => 123
            [XmlVersion] => Testing Version
        )

    [SearchAvailRequest] => Array
        (
            [CountryCd] => ID
            [CityCd] => JOG
            [CheckIn] => 2016-01-08
            [CheckOut] => 2016-01-09
        )

    [SearchAvailResponse] => Array
        (
            [Hotel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [HotelNo] => 1
                            [HotelCode] => 321
                            [HotelName] => Test 1 Hotel
                            [RmGrade] => Deluxe
                            [RmGradeCode] => DLX
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [HotelNo] => 2
                            [HotelCode] => 212
                            [HotelName] => Test 2 & 1 Hotel
                            [RmGrade] => Deluxe
                            [RmGradeCode] => DLX
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to send the hotel data to view

So the view display data like this :

```
Hotel Name
Room Type
```

I try like this :

Controller :

```
...
return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel',[
                                'hotel' => $response_array
            ]);
...
```

View :

```
@foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)
{{ $key }}
{{ $value }}                     
@endforeach
```

But, there exist error like this :

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs...
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through hotels you need to iterate through **$response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel']**, not just **$response_array**.

Try passing **hotel** parameter as the following:

```
return view('frontend.hotel.main_list_hotel',[
  'hotel' => $response_array['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel']
]);
```

And then in your view:

```
@foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)
{{ $key }}
{{ $value['HotelNo'] }}                     
@endforeach
```

Comment: In localhost there is not an error. But there was an error in server. The error is like this : Undefined index: SearchAvailResponse

Comment: It only means there is no SearchAvailResponse in your response_array. Make sure response_array contains the value or check if the key exists before returning it to the view.

Comment: This seems to happen because the public ip on the server has not been registered to access the url api

Comment: I want to display the check in, check out, city and country in view. How to display it all in view? I am confused. Thank you

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36121287/how-to-use-redis-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

You should try this . Here $value is also array

```
@foreach($hotel as $key=>$value)
{{ $key }}
{{ $value['HotelNo'] }}                     
@endforeach
```

Comment: There exist error. The error is like this : `Use of undefined constant HotelNo - assumed 'HotelNo' (View: C:...`